# Ucanaccess driver not found after exporting maven project in NetBeans

Tags: java, maven, ms-access, netbeans, ucanaccess

I'm pretty new to Java, so there might be an easy solution to this:

I get the error message:

> **No suitable driver found for jdbc:ucanaccess://Y:/...**

once I try to establish a connection to a .accdb Database.

However, this only occurs in the exported .jar, which also contains all
needed dependecies, using the *Maven Assembly Plugin* in the *pom.xml*.

Since all other dependencies are working just fine in the exported .jar and the code is connecting to the database flawlessly inside NetBeans, I am a little clueless what could be causing this.

Also I added the ucanaccess-dependency locally in an earlier build, but I am currently using the latest version from the Maven Repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by throwing out Maven and adding the dependencies manually. Although this isn`t very satisfying, the exported .jar now works as intended.

So there seems to be a problem with the Maven Assembly Plugin and Ucanaccess here.